# In Memento, what happened to the money in the Jaguar's trunk?

Tags: plot-explanation, memento

The [final scene of Memento](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqW9fnkhqrs) (which is actually the beginning of the story's timeline) shows Lenny drive off in a Jaguar that has a box full of money in the trunk. Presumably this money is why Dodd tries to catch Lenny later in the timeline, and also why Teddy so badly wants the keys to the Jaguar.

What happens to the money as the timeline develops? Most importantly, what is its status at the end of the timeline, after Lenny has killed Teddy (which is actually the beginning of the movie)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We simply don't know. The trunk or the money don't appear in any of the (chronologically) later scenes. They only play an indirect role as Teddy's motivation to get the car from Leonard. There are only theories about the money's whereabouts.

From [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209144/faq):

> What happened to the money in the trunk of the Jaguar?
>
> This question is never explicitly answered in the film, nor is there really any suggestion as to where it got to. It would appear that Nolan did not consider this a very important detail in his overall narrative of the film, but we may speculate. There are several possibilities that come to mind. (1) At the end of the story it could very well still be in the trunk ready for Leonard to rediscover it and wonder where it came from. (2) Leonard could have during the course of the film already added it to whatever stash of money he has been using for expenses. (3) Teddy could have broken into the car and taken it at some time during the film. (4) It is even possible that Natalie could have used a spare key (it is not unlikely that a couple living together would each have a key to the vehicles), found the money and taken it.